# turbo c++ is not showing fine calculation on my computer

Tags: windows-7, laptop, cpu

there is anybody for helping, i have a hp laptop pavilion 4 with 3gb ram and dual core processor, initially turbo c++(compiler of c)'s curly braces was not working in my laptop but when i have reinstalled my window now the curly braces are working but it shows every time wrong calculation when checked it as alt+f9 to compile and then after when i checked ctrl+f9 it shows always wrong calculation, i have reinstalled it many times but it gives no correct answer, please help if anyone know about it

Comment: I strongly suggest it's doing the calculation correctly and you are simply mistaken about what shoudl happen.

Answer (score 1):

Do you REALLY need to use Turbo C++ on Windows 7? It can be a lot of pain to make it work properly and there are some workarounds:

1. Setup a VM with a old operating system and use Turbo C++ in it;
2. DOSBox will probably work;
3. Integrate the Turbo C++ command line tools and library into your favourite IDE and write your code there (Borland Command Line Toolchain, which was released for free can also be helpful);
4. Migrate your code to newer compiler/toolchain, if it is an option.